# Como rodar banco de dados no Android?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que se conecta em um banco de dados que fica em são paulo, ele serve como uma catraca, verificando pelo `QRCODE` do cartão dos usuários se eles são cadastrados ou não. Só que a empresa para a qual estou trabalhando faz muitas viagens e controla entrada em vários lugares. recebi o aconselhamento de um amigo meu, que o melhor seria baixar o banco para os tablets ao invés de se conectar ao banco através de uma internet. A verdade é que estou com um pouco de medo em relação a isso, pois a internet pode me deixar mal. Mas desconheço métodos para rodar um banco de dados em um sistema `android`(tablets), alguém saberia como e se realmente devo fazer isto?

Obs.: A internet pode ser 3G em alguns lugares ao invés de WI-FI

Comment: Por que não utiliza um webservice? Basta ter um webservice para pegar as informações, seu QR-CODE retorna um `int` e você verifica junto com o webservice.

Comment: Mas com o webservice, será necessário conexão com a internet?

Comment: @RogersCorrêa - Eu pensaria na hipótese de baixar o banco mesmo para os dispositivos e atualizar quando houvesse conexão disponível, para receber os novos dados cadastrados.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e com um tablet rooteado é possível instalar o MySQL. Não é bonito nem recomendável, mas na sua situação pode ajudar: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/your-own-mysql-database-server

Comment: Sim com webservices você precisa de internet! Procure por Android SQLite. Lembrando que um usuário experiente pode alterar esse "banco local" liberando o acesso de qualquer QR-Code, pese os 2 pontos.

Comment: Interessante, mas vou deixar para ultimo caso.

Comment: Acho que isso não resolveria. Pq precisaria estar 'online' da mesma forma.

Comment: Você iria precisar, mas seria uma requisição pequena. O seu problema em utilizar banco local é o usuário alterar esse dado e caso você queira bloquear o usuário de ter o acesso ao local, como faria? A pessoa teria que baixar a sua lista atualizada sempre? E caso não baixou? Então é fundamental você fazer isso com necessidade a conexão com internet.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, sua aplicação android poderia consumir um web service, isso é mais do que comum.

Aqui um tutorial de web service rest
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/

Aqui um tutorial de web service soap
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-webservice-example/

Você também poderia utilizar o sqlite no android, mas acho que seria mais trabalhoso você baixar os banco de dados do seus clientes, até mesmo inviavel.Enfim segue links de com tutorial de aplicação usando sqlite(built-in no android, ja vem com ele)

tutorial sqlite
http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2011/02/17/introducao-ao-sqlite-do-android-criando-e-usando-um-banco-de-dados-baseado-em-sqlite3/

outro tutorial sqlite
http://www.mobiltec.com.br/blog/index.php/android-persistencia-de-dados-usando-sqlite/

espero ter colaborado!

Comment: Paulo, você diz usar os dois, por exemplo, quando não tiver uma internet estável usar local?

Comment: Seria uma solução, dai quando a internet estivesse ok poderia enviar a informação que esta armazenada localmente, ai sua app poderia verificar se estiver conectado e tiver dados à enviar, então poderia fazer. seria uma forma de resolver com contingencia!

Answer (score 1):

Se o problema é internet recomendo a você utilizar o banco local mesmo (Android SQLite), porém, como disse no comentário um usuário experiente pode alterar o banco liberando acesso de outros QR-Code não cadastrados.

Você tem 2 formas de dificultar o acesso a esse banco:

- Encriptar os dados
- Checksum do banco de dados direto no aplicativo.

Com isso, mesmo o usuário alterando o banco e descobrindo a encriptação utilizada ele ainda vai precisar alterar no app que deve ser protegido com **proguard**!